# How to make strings stick together while radix sorting?

Tags: c, arrays, string, sorting, radix-sort

I have to make a program that sort strings (with exact length 7 chars) by using radix sort. I already made a function that sort each column separately. My problem is how to make the whole string move, not just one char. It's really problematic for me to see how should it work in C.

I made one array "char strings[3][8]" and "char output[3][8]" to get sorted 3 strings with exact 7 chars in each one. For example sorting these strings:

```
strcpy(strings[0], "kupbars");
strcpy(strings[1], "daparba");
strcpy(strings[2], "jykaxaw");
```

In output I get:

```
dakaaaa
juparbs
kypbxrw
```

Each column is sorted correctly but chars don't stick together. I tried many ways for 3 hours but nothing works.

My code looks like this:

```
void countingSort(char a[][8], char b[][8]) {
  int c[123];
  for (int pos = 6; pos >= 0; pos--) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 123; i++)
      c[i] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      c[(int)a[i][pos]]++;
    for (int i = 1; i < 123; i++)
      c[i] += c[i - 1];
    for (int i = 2; i >= 0; i--) {
      b[--c[(int)a[i][pos]]][pos] = a[i][pos];
    }
  }
}
```

(There are constants limiting string length etc. because it's easy to change it to variable - I just focused on getting this program work properly.)

Comment: I believe it's usually implemented with a linked list for each digit's bucket, which would have pointers to the entire strings. (You'll need a more complicated data structure; it's difficult to do it in-place)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the loop to move an entire string:

```
    for (int i = 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        int k = --c[(int)a[i][pos]];
        for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            b[k][j] = a[i][j];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! :) Maybe propositions from other users would work too, but yours is the easiest to understand for me

Comment: The inner for loop could be replaced with memcpy() or memmove(), but I was trying use use a basic example.

Comment: @lemka8 don't worry, this answer is good. I ♥ answer like rcgldr did, but my extreme limit is two `for` loop by function. So I don't take your code and propose you a "cleaner" solution. Don't hesitate to try mine later. You need a to understand pointer if you want write in C. By the way, welcome to stack overflow, it was a good question.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a circular list but it's a little overhead. I propose you to use [memmove()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memmove.3.html).

```
#include <string.h>

void array_move_forward(char array[3][8]) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    char tmp = array[i][6];
    memmove(array[i] + 1, array[i], 6);
    array[i][0] = tmp;
  }
}

void array_move_rewind(char array[3][8]) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    char tmp = array[i][0];
    memmove(array[i], array[i] + 1, 6);
    array[i][6] = tmp;
  }
}
```

A other solution would be to manipulate your string yourself and using a index, that indicate the first letter of your string.

```
{
  char str[7];
  int i = 0;
  ...
  int j = i;
  for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++) {
    char tmp = str[j++ % 7];
  }
}
```

With that you could rotate your string just with `i++` or `i--`.

```
struct my_string_radix {
  char str[7];
  int begin;
}
```